# c++ More efficient data structure and algorithm for making a Counter. i used look up tables

Tags: c++, hashmap, counter, lookup, unordered-map

My problem is : i gave a series of queries, and a series of references, and i want to count the number of occurance of said keys between them, but only if they have matching keys. I choose to have an LUT because i think it will help me efficiently, but im not sure if there are better ways, or the way im using LUT is not efficient enough.

i have the following data structures.

```cpp
unordered_map <int, set<int>> Reference_map1, Reference_map2, ... , Reference_mapM;
// to story all the reference maps by their neightas
unordered_map <string, unordered_map <int, set<int>>> ReferenceMaps;
unordered_map <int, set<string>> LUT // look up table
// N is significantly greater than M
unordered_map <int, set<int>> query_map1, query_map2, ... , query_mapN;
```

Example of `Reference_mapi` and `query_mapj`

```cpp
Reference_map1[111] = {0, 1, 2};
Reference_map1[333] = {1, 2, 3};
Reference_map1[888] = {2, 8, 0};

Reference_map2[111] = {1, 5, 9};
Reference_map2[999] = {0, 7, 4};

ReferenceMaps['Reference_map1']=Reference_map1;
ReferenceMaps['Reference_map2']=Reference_map2;

query_map1[111] = {8, 2, 6};
query_map1[333] = {4, 7, 3};

query_map2[222] = {3, 6, 8};
query_map2[999] = {2, 3, 5};
```

How i store my look up table `LUT`
This is so that for whatever keys i get from 'query_mapj', i only get the necessary `Reference_mapi`s

```cpp
LUT[111] = {'Reference_map1', 'Reference_map2'}
LUT[333] = {'Reference_map1'}
LUT[888] = {'Reference_map1'}
LUT[999] = {'Reference_map2'}
```

For example `111` from `query_map1` gives both 'Reference_map1', 'Reference_map2' as they have the key `111`.
On the other hand, `999` from `query_map2` only gives 'Reference_map2' as only it have the key `999`.

So it will go like this:

```cpp
unordered_map<string, int> MakeCounter(
    unordered_map <int, set<int>> &query_map, 
    unordered_map <string, unordered_map <int, set<int>>> &ReferenceMaps
    ){
    unordered_map<string, int> RefName_Counter;
    set<string> ReferenceNameSet;
    // Update the RefName_Counter
    for (const auto &key2nameset:query_map) {
        // Check if this hash is in the LUT
        if (LUT.count(key2nameset.first) <= 0){ continue; }
        // Update Counter
        ReferenceNameSet = LUT[key2nameset.first];
        for (const auto &it : ReferenceNameSet){
            if (RefName_Counter.count(it) > 0)
                RefName_Counter[it]++;
            else
                RefName_Counter[it] = 1;
        }
    }
    return RefName_Counter;
}

// The results should be like this
Counter1 = MakeCounter(query_map1, ReferenceMaps);
/*
    Counter1['Reference_map1'] = 2; // because they share keys : 111 and 333
    Counter1['Reference_map2'] = 1; // because they share keys : 111
*/
Counter2 = MakeCounter(query_map2, ReferenceMaps);
/*
    Counter1['Reference_map2'] = 1; // because they share keys : 999
*/
```

Is there a better way to get `Counteri` for each respective `query_mapi` ?

Comment: It appears that you are not using the `value` part of your maps `unordered_map <int, set<int>>` (`set<int>`) to produce your counters, so you could use just `set`  of keys instead of `map`. The suffixes `1..N` suggest that you should use vectors instead. So it may look like `vector<set<int>> Reference_map` and so on. This will make your `ReferenceMaps` obsolete (replaced by the index into that vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering my comment above, here is what I got.

Adjusted to keep original data, but this feels like an extra credit :)

```
unordered_map<int,int> MakeCounter(const unordered_map <int, set<int>>& qs, 
  const vector<unordered_map <int, set<int>>>& refs)
{
  unordered_map<int, int> counters;
  for (size_t i = 0;  i < refs.size(); ++i)
  {
    for (auto q : qs)
    {
      if (refs[i].find(q.first) != refs[i].end())
        counters[i]++;
    }
  }
  return counters;
}

int main()
{
  vector<unordered_map <int, set<int>>> References = {
    { {111, { 0, 1, 2 } },
      {333, { 1, 2, 3 } },
      {888, { 2, 8, 0 } },
    },
    { {111, { 1, 5, 9 } },
      {999, { 0, 7, 4 } },
    }
  };

  vector<unordered_map <int, set<int>>> Queries = {
    { {111, { 8, 2, 6 } },
      {333, { 4, 7, 3 } },
    },
    { {222, { 3, 6, 8 } },
      {999, { 2, 3, 5 } },
    }
  };
  unordered_map<int, int> m0 = MakeCounter(Queries[0], References);
  unordered_map<int, int> m1 = MakeCounter(Queries[1], References);
}
```

Comment: I didnt show in the question how i used the values, but they are required for a post-processing down the road, could you change your answer to still keep the original data structure? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a comment; I am using "answer" to properly format code fragments.

This searches your `LUT` twice:

```
// Check if this hash is in the LUT
if (LUT.count(key2nameset.first) <= 0){ continue; }
// Update Counter
ReferenceNameSet = LUT[key2nameset.first];
```

It also makes a copy of the set for no reason.

I believe that indexing a non-existing element in the map inserts that element, so

```
if (RefName_Counter.count(it) > 0)
    RefName_Counter[it]++;
else
    RefName_Counter[it] = 1;
```

is effectively:

```
RefName_Counter[it]++;
```

So your outer `for` loop becomes:

```
for (const auto &key2nameset:query_map) {
    // Check if this hash is in the LUT
    auto iter = LUT.find(key2nameset.first);
    if(iter == LUT.end()) { continue; }
    // Update Counter
    for (const auto &it : *iter){
        RefName_Counter[it]++;
}
```

Comment: `auto iter = LUT.find(key2nameset.first);` is this a copy ?

Comment: @leonardltk1 - no, but your original `ReferenceNameSet = LUT[key2nameset.first];` is